# Docker - passing new content to production

Tags: image, docker, containers, backup

I' m new to Docker and still searching for a safe way to update production code without losing any valuable data.

So far the way we update our production machine is like this:

- docker build the new code
- docker push the image
- docker pull the image (on the preferred machine)
- docker stack rm && docker stack deploy

I' ve read countless guides about backups, but still can't understand if you lose something and what this is if you don't backup and something goes wrong. So I have some questions:

1. When you docker stack rm the container, you delete it? And if yes do I lose something by doing that (e.g volumes)?
2. Should I backup the container and its volumes (which i still don't understand how to do it), or just the image? Or just create a new tag when docker build my new code and I am safe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `docker rm` a container, you delete the container filesystem, but you don't affect any volumes that might have been attached to that container.  If you `docker run` a new container that mounts the same volumes, it will see their content.

You'd never back up an entire container.  You do need to back up the contents of volumes.

A good practice is to design your application to not store anything in local files at all: store absolutely everything in a database or other "remote" storage.  The actual storage doesn't have to be in Docker.  Then you can back up the database the same way you would any other database, and freely delete and create as many copies of the container as you need (possibly by adjusting replica counts in Swarm or Kubernetes).